# Covering a set $A \subset \Bbb R$ by two families of disjoint intervals taken from given intervals

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $A \subset \Bbb R$ be a bounded set. Every element $a \in A$ is the center of some given open interval, let's denote it by $I_a=(a-r_a, a+r_a)$. I'm interested in knowing the following:

> Can we always color some of the given intervals $I_a$ in red and some others in blue such that intervals of the same color are disjoint, and the colored intervals together contain all of $A$?

I know that there is some constant number of colors that suffices for all possible $A$ and $I_a$, and this holds even in higher dimensions for different constants; this is [Besicovitch's covering theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Besicovitch_covering_theorem). Thus we can rephrase the question as:

> what is the optimal constant for Besicovitch's covering theorem in $\Bbb R$?

Note that $A$ is not necessarily closed, so it seems we cannot choose some "extremal" values such as largest intervals to construct a greedy approach to coloring.

A now-deleted answer linked to [this post](https://sunlimingbit.wordpress.com/2012/02/17/covering-theorems-of-the-besicovitch-type/#comment-2319) containing a proof. However, I don't understand the proof at all. So it suffices if someone would write it in a way that is easier to comprehend.

Comment: Is $r(a)$ given or can we choose it?

Comment: @abnry It is given.

Comment: $I_{a}\subseteq A$?

Comment: @MariosGretsas Those finitely many intervals need not exist, since the given intervals need not cover the closure of $A$. Say $A=(0,1)$ and $r_a=\min\{a,1-a\}$. Then the $I_a$ cover only $(0,1)$ but not $[0,1]$.